# More than 1 log file was rolling at the same time using logback

Tags: logback

I am using logback for rolling and below is my rolling configuration

```
<appender name="rtc_file_appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DEST}</file>
    <Append>true</Append>
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>%date | [%.-1level] | %logger | %X{threadId} | %msg%n</Pattern>            
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
        <FileNamePattern>rtc.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>5MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>
```

when application is in use, first rtc.log file is created and then rtc.log.1 and then tc.log.2 etc..

But, this this configuration after rolling one log file (eg: rtc.log.1), it started rolling the logs in rtc.log.2 and at the same time rtc.log.1 file was opened again and start rolling.

Means, two log files are in open mode and rolling the log.

Please advice , how this can be fixed.

Comment: Share the Java code.

Comment: I don't see any issue with java code. Need help to share if any issue with my logback configuration